# Swift 3. Can present a UIViewController with UIWebViewDelegate but not push it

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIWebViewDelegate`. I found that I can present it just fine but not push it. If I try to push it the target view controller loads and executes any variables set but does not fire `viewDidLoad()` and instead just returns to my calling menu view controller without error.

I set a breakpoint on the first var declaration after the class and stepped through the code. When it got to webView init it flashed up the home (not target) view controller in the simulator and then continued though the var declarations before returning back to my home view controller.

Here is my menu code

works:

```
let myWebViewController = MyWebViewController()

myWebViewController.urlString = "myUrl"

present(myWebViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

does not work

```
let myWebViewController = MyWebViewController()

myWebViewController.urlString = "myUrl"

let navController = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).navController

navController!.pushViewController(myWebViewController, animated: true)
```

Here is my redacted target view controller code. The URL to load is set in the menu.

```
import UIKit

class MyWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

var urlString: String = "invalid url"

var url: URL {
    return URL(string: urlString)!
}

var urlRequest: URLRequest {

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    return urlRequest
}

let webView: UIWebView = {
    let view = UIWebView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

// declare various buttons and stack views 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(webView)

    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(contentStackView)

    view.addSubview(mainStackView)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code? The phrase `present(myWebViewController...` is or `navController!.pushViewController` is meaningless if you don't show where you got the variable `myWebViewController` from — and I suspect that somewhere in there, in the code you have not shown, is _exactly_ the source of the issue. — Also, please go back thru all your code and make all _classes start with a capital letter_. So this would be a variable `myWebViewController` whose type is `MyWebViewController`.

Comment: The lower case class name was a typo here only. I have updated my question to add more code.

Comment: Since the target view starts to load I don't think the menu code is the problem but that may be wrong.

Comment: I don't understand either what the problem is or how your code is supposed to work. Your MyWebViewController contains no code that would actually put the UIWebView into the interface, fetch a URL, or anything useful.

Comment: Added more code. Presenting the target view controller works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the web view, the web view controller, or anything else except where you're pushing the view controller. You are saying:

```
let navController = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).navController
navController!.pushViewController(myWebViewController, animated: true)
```

That is highly unusual. The usual thing is that we are inside a navigation interface already, and we push onto its stack:

```
let navController = self.navigationController
navController!.pushViewController(myWebViewController, animated: true)
```

But you are not saying that. Why not? I'm guessing it's because `self` does not *have* a `navigationController`. So you are successfully pushing onto the navigation controller, all right, but you are not *seeing* anything happening because the navigation controller is *behind the scenes* — the `self` view controller's view is blocking it or has replaced it.

And that explains why you never detect the url loading. Your call to `webView.loadRequest` is in `viewWillAppear`. But this view will *not* appear; it is behind the scenes. `viewWillAppear` is never called. Similarly `viewDidLoad` is not called, because this view is *not* going to load; the navigation controller is not occupying the interface — `self` is.

Comment: I am aware that the calling view controller has no navigation controller but then how do I bring it to the front with the root navigation controller? Thanks for the extra insight regarding `viewWillAppear()` A breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()` shows that it is never triggered either.

Comment: Taking out the call to the app delegate nav controller results in a crash due to nil. The side menu does not have a navigation controller and I don't see how it could have unless I hide it which seems like a hack.

Comment: "Taking out the call to the app delegate nav controller results in a crash due to nil" Correct, because `self` has no navigation controller, as I said.

Comment: I don't know anything about your "side menu" because you have said nothing about it. Your question doesn't mention it! But the whole point is that `self`, whatever it is, is occupying the interface. You won't get any call to `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` until you get `self` out of the way and let the navigation controller occupy the interface. You would need to _dismiss_ `self` in some way _first_, before trying to do the push.

Answer (score 1):

I could possibly think of one scenario why the webViewController is not being pushed.

The UIViewController from which you are trying to make the push might not be part of the navigation controller hierarchy.

Why don't you try using the code instead of getting the navController from AppDelegate

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myWebViewController, animated: true)
```

If this doesn't work out then your are certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: This crashes. I know that the UITableView menu doesn't have a navigation controller. The question is how to get one for the view to load?

Comment: Make your tableviewcontroller as rootviewcontroller of UINavigationController and it should work.